# In kinetic theory when can we ignore forces?

Tags: kinetic-theory

Let us say I have a body of gas for which there is an external force $F$ (which could be say gravity) acting on the particles. What conditions should $F$ satisfy before I can assume that the effect of this force is negligible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to know the rough mean free path of the gaseous system. Then you take a stationary particle and find out the net change in kinetic energy if the force moves athe particle through the distance given by the mean free path. If the change in the kinetic energy is very very small as compared to the average thermal kinetic energy of the particles in the system, the force can be safely ignored, as the collisions with other particles will dictate the dynamics rather than the force itself. In case of gravity, since it is very weak, the net change in kinetic energy due to gravitation over the mean free path length is very much less than the average thermal kinetic energy and so it doesn't play an appreciable rolein the dynamics of the gas.